# .change not triggered if change the value by js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In my web page the value of an input is changing by a js application, but what I want is to trigger an event when a value is changed.

The problem is that when the value is changed by the application, no event is triggered because the value is changed by js but if a value is input by the user the event is triggered.

Here is a small example of this, when you click on the `change button`, the value is changed but the `.change` event does not trigger.

If you manually input the values `.change` will trigger.

```js
var i = 0;
$("#id_st").change(function(){
  console.log('This is value',$(this).val())
  $('#p').html($(this).val());
});

$('#change_btn').click(function(){
  i = i+1;
  $("#id_st").val(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_st" type="text" name="st" value="0">
<br>
<button id="change_btn" type="button" name="button">change value</button>
<br>
<p id="p">value</p>
```

I searched for my problem and found `.trigger('change')` but as I already told you that value is changed by an application which I haven't developed so can't use this method.

Please tell me a real solution for my problem.

Comment: Have you ever consider using RxJS?

Answer (score 5):

On `button#change_btn` click , the change event of the `input#id_st` wont't be fired. This is because for `input` element to fire `change` event, first it's value must change and then it must loose focus. So when you click the button, it's value has changed but it never got focus to loose it later.

So you have to fire the 'change' event manually for which you can just chain `trigger()` once you set the value of the input with `val()` as

```
$("#id_st").val(i).trigger('change')
```

You can learn more here in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Demo:

```js
var i = 0;
$("#id_st").change(function(){
  console.log('This is value',$(this).val())
  $('#p').html($(this).val());
});

$('#change_btn').click(function(){
  i = i+1;
  $("#id_st").val(i).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_st" type="text" name="st" value="0">
<br>
<button id="change_btn" type="button" name="button">change value</button>
<br>
<p id="p">value</p>
```

EDIT:

Well if you can't use `trigger()`. You can check for change in value of the `input` periodically as suggested by @Mohammad.

Comment: This is what I thought in the beginning till I notice OP said *and found .trigger('change') but as I already told you that value is changed by an application which I haven't developed so can't use this method*

Comment: ahh! Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef , I missed that part.

Comment: I missed it before you :-) .. have a great day

Answer (score 0):

use `.on('input')` and `trigger('input')`

```js
var i = 0;
$("#id_st").on('input',function(){
  console.log('This is value',$(this).val())
  $('#p').html($(this).val());
  // you may need to update i here to start from it after change
  i = parseInt($(this).val());
});

$('#change_btn').click(function(){
  i = i+1;
  $("#id_st").val(i).trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_st" type="text" name="st" value="0">
<br>
<button id="change_btn" type="button" name="button">change value</button>
<br>
<p id="p">value</p>
```

**Sorry!!** misunderstanding here.. Unfortunately What I know is: you cannot make the `change` event fire itself without relation between the event/action and the input .. **OR** you have to use `setInterval()` to catch any change of input value after each amount of time

This is how to `trigger` the event using `setInterval()` without need to `trigger` the event in the uncontrolled application

```js
var i = 0;
$("#id_st").on('input',function(){
  console.log('This is value',$(this).val())
  $('#p').html($(this).val());
  // you may need to update i here to start from it after change
  i = parseInt($(this).val());
});

$('#change_btn').click(function(){
  i = i+1;
  $("#id_st").val(i);
});

// setInterval every 5 seconds
setInterval(function(){
  $("#id_st").trigger('input');
} , 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_st" type="text" name="st" value="0">
<br>
<button id="change_btn" type="button" name="button">change value</button>
<br>
<p id="p">value</p>
```

Comment: sorry to say but `setInterval()` is not  a good solution for me because I need to trigger event just after change in value and also only trigger when the value is changed

Answer (score 0):

If you're not the one who's changing the value, then I think there's only one way to trigger the change, you'll have to put a setTimOout() function on the input which will take the value of the `<p>` and check if it's different from the one before.
(In page load capture the `<p>` value and every time your setTimeOut() runs update that value).
If it's different then trigger the change with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on MDN web docs, i found some stuff on manually firing events [Dispatch Event Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```js
var i = 0;
$("#id_st").change(function(){
  console.log('This is value',$(this).val())
  $('#p').html($(this).val());
});

$('#change_btn').click(function(){
  var event = new Event('change');
  var target = document.getElementById('id_st');
  i = i+1;
  $("#id_st").val(i);
  target.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_st" type="text" name="st" value="0">
<br>
<button id="change_btn" type="button" name="button">change value</button>
<br>
<p id="p">value</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I already mentioned that the value is being changed by external application, so can't use these methods !!!